# How can I set text orientation in Excel using matlab actxserver?

Tags: matlab

I'm using matlab actxserver to make a excel table. I want to change the orientation of text in a cell. I have checked some VBA codes. But I don't know how to transform a VBA command in Matlab code. I have tried:

```matlab
eSheet.Range.Orientation=90;
eSheet.Range.XlOrientation=-4171;
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlorientation)
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.orientation)
They don't work.

What's the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! "_Is there a good guide anywhere for the matlab activex syntax versions of VBA commands?_" Are you looking for an "official" resource (written by the maintainers of matlab) or are you looking for any resource? Requests for non-official learning resources are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you are asking for official resources, please [edit] to state that. If you are looking for any resources, please remove that request from your question an ask it somewhere else where it is on-topic :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I agree with most of what you said, but my understanding is that [requests for official documentation are allowed and on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541).

Comment: What do you mean they "don't work"? Do you have MATLAB code you can [edit] into your question to show how you're defining `eSheet`? That should be through a couple of lines including the `actxserver()` function. Do you then get an error? Or unexpected behaviour?